# Google Static Maps API - getting key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am developing a small application, which would use Google Static Maps API.
To do this, do the following steps...

1. I go to the Google Developers Console and and choose a my project  that you created earlier
2. From enabled APIs I choose Static Maps API
3. Then I create a Browser Key

[image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5Jx.jpg)

4. After that, the API state does not change, it remains disable

[image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFS4i.jpg)

The same thing happens if I choose to experiment with a different type of key or another API.

What is my fault?

Comment: Did you actually enable the Static Maps API?

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is okay and that the Google Static Maps API is enabled. If you are looking at the list of 'enabled APIs', and off in a column on the right you see the word "Disable", that means that the APIs in that list are enabled for the selected project, but if you want to selectively disable an API in the project, you can click on the word "Disable" in the column on the right.